# Inserting photo directly from webcam in to cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

For my job I am creating an Excel sheet, taking pictures and putting the pictures in to cells.

It would really make my job a lot easier if I could insert a picture in to a cell straight from the camera. At the moment I have to take the picture with another application, save it somewhere, then select insert picture in Excel, find it in Explorer and insert it.

Is there a more direct way to insert a picture from the webcam/camera on my tablet directly in to a cell?

Comment: It's not an answer, but I'm curious why you're using Excel to store images from a webcam? Perhaps there's a better option?

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If you're an Office 365 using Office Mobile for Windows 10, yes you can with **Insert > Pictures > Camera**. Otherwise, I believe that's not possible.

[image]

Microsoft:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-picture-from-the-camera-17e509d0-8079-4ce6-a2cc-652e4b8092d2